# delete with returning rowtype?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Main goal: I want to move records in small chunks from "working" table to archive.

Prepare:

```
create table working_tmp as select * from all_objects;
create table archive_tmp as select * from all_objects where 1=2;
```

Plan:

- delete records from working_tmp into collection.
- insert collection into archive_tmp.

First attempt:

```
declare
    type t_arr is table of working_tmp%rowtype;
    v_data t_arr;
begin
    delete from working_tmp 
    where owner = 'SYS'
    returning
      OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID, 
      DATA_OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_TYPE, CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME, 
      TIMESTAMP, STATUS, TEMPORARY, GENERATED, 
      SECONDARY, NAMESPACE, EDITION_NAME
    bulk collect into v_data;

    forall i in v_data.first..v_data.last
        insert into archive_tmp values v_data(i);
end;
```

This is working, but I don't like part in upper case.. what if someone later add a column to a table?

Second attempt:

```
declare
    type t_arr is table of working_tmp%rowtype;
    v_data t_arr;
begin
    delete from working_tmp v 
    where owner = 'SYS'
    returning v.* bulk collect into v_data;

    forall i in v_data.first..v_data.last
        insert into archive_tmp values v_data(i);
end;
```

This is not working.. bad syntax.

Let's try dynamic:

```
declare
    type t_arr is table of working_tmp%rowtype;
    v_data t_arr;
    v_col_list varchar2(32000);
begin
    select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id) 
    into v_col_list
    from user_tab_cols
    where table_name = 'WORKING_TMP';

    execute immediate
         'delete from working_tmp v where owner = ''SYS'' returning ' || v_col_list || ' returning :data'
    returning bulk collect into v_data';

    forall i in v_data.first..v_data.last
        insert into archive_tmp values v_data(i);
end;
```

This one gives me 'PLS-00429: unsupported feature with RETURNING clause'

I can do select, then delete, then insert. But is there a way to do it with 2 statements and not with 3?

Is it possible to return rowtype from DELETE statement?
Am I missing something?

Comment: I've got a similar opportunity in 12c SE. In my case I want to change one of the column in the primary key. I'm deleting the old record then merging back in with the column changed. It's the same problem.  I've tried `RETURNING ROW` rather than `RETURNING v.*`, no luck.  Can this sort of thing be done?

Comment: You can rename or change datatype of a column without any data movement. If you need details or problem is more complex - create a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your working case is good enough. If somebody add a column, this statement will became uncompileable (invalid if described as stored proc) so he'll see it and will edit it.

Generally 'move from worker to archive table' is doubtful idea, first of all you should check if you really need it. Usually eitgher it is not required at all or exists cheaper way to do this.

The simpliest way to do such moving is to use partitioning with row movement option. You should add a flag column - is records active or archived - at make an 'active' and 'archive' partitions based on it. When somebody will mark record as archived - it will be automatically moved to archive partition.

Comment: You are right, first attempt will "fail fast" (haven't thought of that). But if I can get to zero maintenance - it is even better.